# Rails 4 - filter index via collection_select values in a form on index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, scope, ruby-on-rails-4, filtering

```
Record:
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :course
  has_one :client, through: :user
  has_one :group, through: :user
```

On the index action page for the Record I would like to have a form with collection_selects for client, group, and user (the form, I with relevant collection_selects have already made) … But I do not know how to make the form submit button return a filtered index page.

I have the scopes setup just don't know how to call them from the form.

Record Model w/ scopes: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/tpayne84/test_tracker/blob/master/app/models/record.rb)

_index_filter_form Partial View: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/tpayne84/test_tracker/blob/master/app/views/records/_index_filter.html.erb)

Records Controler: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/tpayne84/test_tracker/blob/master/app/controllers/records_controller.rb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally I had this as my  in the view:

```
<td><%= collection_select(:client_id, 0, Client.find(:all, :order => "name"), :id, :name, {}, {:class=>'form-control'}) %></td>
<td><%= collection_select(:group_id, 0, Group.find(:all, :order => "name"), :id, :name, {}, {:class=>'form-control'}) %></td>
<td><%= collection_select(:user_id, 0, User.find(:all, :order => "first_name, last_name"), :id, :full_name, {}, {:class=>'form-control'}) %></td>
```

I went back to look at how I was passing my parameters... and revised the code above:

```
<!-- collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}) -->
<td><%= collection_select(:client, :id, Client.find(:all, :order => "name"), :id, :name, {}, {:class=>'form-control'}) %></td>
<td><%= collection_select(:group, :id, Group.find(:all, :order => "name"), :id, :name, {}, {:class=>'form-control'}) %></td>
<td><%= collection_select(:user, :id, User.find(:all, :order => "first_name, last_name"), :id, :full_name, {:multiple => true, :size => 5}, {:class=>'form-control'}) %></td>
```

Now I can access the params via the index action on the controller after the form submission.

```
def index
    @records = Record.all
    if params[:commit] == "Filter"
      @records.by_client(params[:client_id]).by_group(params[:group_id]).by_user(params[:user_id])
    end
end
```

Where the by_client, by_group, and by_user are named scopes located in the Record Model.